# The records can be inserted in the db and can be fetched (with mongoose), but when I log into the mongodb, it is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am following this tutorial to understand how mongoose interacts with mongodb: http://blog.modulus.io/getting-started-with-mongoose

I have created a schema and a model. When I save the data, I get a console callback, that gives me out everything, I have saved. When I find the information, it also gets logged out. But when I log into mongo via terminal, use the mydb and execute the query `db.mydb.find().pretty()`, I get no results.,

What might be the problem? I am using exactly the same code, as in the tutorial.

This is the code, in case it will help to find the problem, somehow:

This is in the app.js

```
var db = mongoose.connection;

// console errors
db.on('error', console.error);
// load models
db.once('open', function() {
  fs.readdirSync(__dirname = './models/').forEach(function(filename) {
    if(~filename.indexOf('.js')) {require('./models/' + filename)};
  });
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
```

*So it basically creates the connection, loads all of the models from the folder and consoles an error, if it occures (it does not).

Here is the code from my user model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var usersSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    admin: Boolean
});

var User = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);
```

Here I insert the user:

```
    var danny = new User({
    name: 'Danny',
    age: 25,
    admin: true
});
danny.save(function(err, res) {
    if (err) { return console.error(err) };
    console.dir(res);
});
```

*It logs out this user, when saved.

If I find all the users, I get the list of the same user (because It was accidentally saved multiple times). To find all, I use this command:

```
User.find(function(err, res) {
    console.dir(res);
});
```

If I log in mongodb using command `mongo` on my Ubuntu Linux, and then I switch to the database with command `use mydb` and then `db.mydb.find().pretty()` It prints out nothing

Comment: I do not think there is something wrong with the tutorial so there must be a mistake in your code... Can you share it please?

Comment: Which one? P.S. I am using express framework

Comment: Give me the create function.

Comment: Try this: "use mydb" and then "db.users.find().pretty()" (both times without the quotes). Does that work?

Comment: @ThomasBormans no.. It logs out this - `function (){ this._prettyShell = true; return this; }`

Comment: And `db.users.find()`?

Comment: Try the following: `use mydb` & `db.getCollectionNames()`. Can you give me the result of that?

Comment: @ThomasBormans Holy...... You solved it! It works! `use mydb` && `db.users.find()` Can you please post it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct. And I would really appriciate, if you will explain, me how did that work? I mean what is `users` in the db and why didnt it log it out when calling the basic db.mydb.find() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a small mistake when querying the database through the Mongo shell. Instead of using `db.mydb.find().pretty()`, you should use `db.users.find().pretty()`.

Here is why:

You are connecting to your database with this line in Mongoose:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');
```

The `mydb` at the end will be the name of your database. So you might want to change this to something else so it is easier to recognise the database in the future.

In the Mongo shell, you are switching your database correctly using `use mydb`. To query your collection, you will need the following syntax:

```
DB + collection name + command() + extra stuff();
```

This means you will get the following command:

```
db.users.find().pretty();
```

The reason you should be using `users`, is because of this line:

```
var User = mongoose.model('Users', usersSchema);
```

`Users` will be the name of your collection. **Please note** that if you used `User`, Mongoose would have added an "s" to your collection name. To overwrite this, you can use this line:

```
usersSchema('collection', 'user');
```

Now your collection will always get the name `user`.